# Disable normal key function in JS

Tags: javascript, web

I want to call a function if the Windows-Key is pressed, but if I press it, the Start-Menu opens...
Is there any possible way to prevent this?

Comment: There is a reason for this ...

Comment: Why do you wanna you windows key? Check this out: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/216893/how-to-enable-or-disable-the-keyboard-windows-key

Answer (score 1):

You can catch in this way. You can not only interfere with the start menu. You only have the chance to interfere with the components running on the Web browser.

```js
document.onkeydown = function(evt){
    if(evt.keyCode == 91) {
       console.log('windows button');
    }
    evt.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.onkeypress = function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 91 || e.keyCode == 92) {
        console.log("Windows button was pressed")
    }
};
```